# Long running SQL query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query that for some reason is causing Access 2007-2010 to just hang and I assume it's because the query is just taking forever.  I have never waited long enough to see if it ever returns results.

I have a table "MAIN" with 100k+ home addresses and another table, "ALIAS" with 100's of addresses.  The "MAIN" table is the records I want to return.  The "ALIAS" table has a small subset of addresses from MAIN with other addresses that don't exist in MAIN.  The ALIAS table exists to group sets of addresses that are related.  Think of it as current/MAIN addresses and old/ALIAS addresses.  They share an ID in the ALIAS table so I know which are related.

So to query for an address and return the address in the MAIN table OR anything in the MAIN table that has a record relation in the ALIAS table.  Here's an example:

MAIN
number, direction, name, type
123 W 1st ST
456 W 1st ST

ALIAS
number, direction, name, type, groupID
456 W 1st ST 99
789 E 2nd ST 99
So if a user queries for 789 E 2nd ST it should return 456 W 1st ST from MAIN because the 789 address exists in the ALIAS table and is related to 456, AND 456 also is in MAIN.

Here is the query that I have and it's running too long and may take days to return...

```
SELECT dbo_ae_dt9.docid, dbo_ae_dt9.ID, dbo_ae_dt9.Permit, dbo_ae_dt9.stDirection, 
dbo_ae_dt9.stNumber, dbo_ae_dt9.stType, dbo_ae_dt9.inspDate, dbo_ae_dt9.stName, 
dbo_ae_dt9.numobjects
FROM dbo_ae_dt9 LEFT JOIN dbo_ae_alias ON 
(dbo_ae_dt9.stNumber=dbo_ae_alias.stNumber) AND 
(dbo_ae_dt9.stDirection=dbo_ae_alias.stDirection) AND 
(dbo_ae_dt9.stName=dbo_ae_alias.stName) AND 
(dbo_ae_dt9.stType=dbo_ae_alias.stType)
WHERE (dbo_ae_alias.aliasID in  
   (SELECT aliasID   
    FROM dbo_ae_alias  
    WHERE ((IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstName),dbo_ae_alias.stName like "*", dbo_ae_alias.stName=Forms!frmMain!txtstName)) AND
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstNumber),dbo_ae_alias.stNumber like "*", dbo_ae_alias.stNumber=Forms!frmMain!txtstNumber)) AND
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstDirection),dbo_ae_alias.stDirection like "*", dbo_ae_alias.stDirection=Forms!frmMain!txtstDirection)) AND
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstType),dbo_ae_alias.stType like "*", dbo_ae_alias.stType=Forms!frmMain!txtstType))))) OR
    ((IIf(IsNull([Forms]![frmMain]![txtPermit]),dbo_ae_dt9.Permit Like "*",dbo_ae_dt9.Permit = Forms!frmMain!txtPermit)) And
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstNumber),dbo_ae_dt9.stNumber Like "*",dbo_ae_dt9.stNumber = Forms!frmMain!txtstNumber)) And
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstDirection),dbo_ae_dt9.stDirection Like "*",dbo_ae_dt9.stDirection = Forms!frmMain!txtstDirection)) And 
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstName),dbo_ae_dt9.stName Like "*",dbo_ae_dt9.stName = Forms!frmMain!txtstName)) And 
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstType),dbo_ae_dt9.stType Like "*",dbo_ae_dt9.stType = Forms!frmMain!txtstType)) And 
    (IIf(IsNull(Forms!frmMain!txtstInspDate),dbo_ae_dt9.inspDate Like "*",dbo_ae_dt9.inspDate = Forms!frmMain!txtstInspDate)))
```

Comment: The like statements are obviously your culprit...why so many checks to make sure there are "*"?  (like is horribly optimized in Access and barely function as a single like.  You have 10 of them)

Comment: If a user doesn't enter anything in a field I want it to act like a wildcard in that field.  So I was checking the form for null and if so using like "*" to get any results for that column.  Otherwise saying txtstName=alias.stname wouldn't work when they don't enter something.

Comment: Your entire architecture is flawed if you need all of those `IIf(IsNull(..Like` clauses. You've written probably the least efficient `WHERE` clause you could write (in a sub-select, no less), and then are complaining that the performance is bad. You need to step back and re-think your entire design; I don't think there's anything even remotely salvageable here.